# Can Tableau Desktop be automatically refreshed when the database is updated

Tags: tableau-api

I'm using Tableau Desktop 9.0 to create a visualization  by extracting the data from DB2 database. But this database is updated everyday. That is, at the every time the data in the database changes. So is it possible for me to schedule a task of refreshing the extracted data source automatically at specific interval of time so that, after updating the report should reflect the results accordingly. Can this be done through Tableau Desktop automatically?  The main thing is that it can easily be done on Tableau Server as known. But I cannot afford for a Server so I'm trying to get an answer is it possible with the Tableau Desktop or not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to refresh the extracted datasource automatically in Tableau Desktop at specific intervals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27782900/how-to-refresh-the-extracted-datasource-automatically-in-tableau-desktop-at-spec)

Comment: Follow that link. Tableau Desktop does not support scheduling extracts, didn't changed that on 9.0

Comment: I was wrong. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191737/sending-keys-to-tableau-with-a-script

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Tableau Data Extract Command-Line Utility](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/help.html#extracting_TDE.html) in a batch script (like DOS/cmd or PowerShell) and schedule the batch script to run on the Windows Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Windows. Use Task Scheduler to schedule (a variation of) the following Powershell script on a daily basis.

```
C:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau 9.0\bin>tableau refreshextract--server
https://blah_blah_server_name --username YourServerSignIn --password 
YourServerPwd  --datasource "Some_Table" --source-username YourDatabaseSignIn
--source-password YourDatabasePassword
```