# Sending keys to Tableau with a script

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, tableau-api

I am actually using Tableau Software Desktop and saving my workbooks to .twbx (tableau data extract + tableau workbooks) and I need to refresh my tableau data extract ( not the view ) every 4 hours. I found out that there are plenty of ways to do it with Tableau online but none with tableau desktop. What I am thinking of, would be to send the keys in a power shell script to Tableau to automatically refresh the .TDE ( which is connected to a psql database ).

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 2):

Use the tableau command line tool to refresh or append to an extract as often as desired, or call from a script
http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/help.html#extracting_TDE.html

Or if necessary, write your own extract utility using the Tableau Data Extract API

You probably will want to save your extract data source separate from workbooks that reference it. That is save the extract to a .tde file and then save your workbook in a .twb file (not a .twbx) unless you have other reasons to package your workbook. That way you can refresh or replace the extract without touching the workbook(s) that reference it.

Comment: Cool, didn't know they included this on 9.0