# Tableau Desktop refresh, connect to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, scheduled-tasks, tableau-api

I'm making some semi-live dashboards for my team, with pulled-data updated daily. This question got me about 70% of the way: [Can Tableau Desktop be automatically refreshed when the database is updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30108521/)

Specs are: Running windows 8, I have Tableau Desktop 10.1, data from SQL Server 2005, but extracted into a .tde

I need that final 30%, which is a bunch of some basic questions:

1. In task scheduler, can I just run the command options as an argument (eg. tableau refreshextract), or do I have to create a separate .bat file?
2. our database uses windows authentication, do I still need to state the username & password in parameters?
3. In task scheduler, can I set to refresh multiple workbooks at one time, or is it better to execute separate instances?
4. the .tde - I noticed it's stored locally. If the workbook is stored on a network folder, will it need to reference my tde, or do I have to move it somehow?

Thanks for any help!